# PHP Mysqli Insert data on foreign key enabled table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two page: addbroker.php
addbroker.inc.php

from **addbroker.php** we are fetching brokername as following with dropdown list & accountno, accountname get added via form.

```
  <?php
         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT brokername FROM brokerlist '); 
         $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
         $stmt->bind_result($brokername);
         $stmt->store_result();
         echo "<select name='brokername'>";
         while($stmt->fetch()) {
         echo "<option value='" . $brokername . "'>" . $brokername . "</option>";
          }
         $stmt->close();
         echo "</select>";
         ?> <br>
```

on **addbroker.inc.php**
we are adding data for masterbroker where **user_id**, **brokername**, **broker_id** are the foreign key.

```
// Insert the new account into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO masterbroker (user_id, accountno,accountname,brokername,revenue,broker_id) VALUES ( (SELECT user_id FROM client WHERE user_id =?), ?, ?,  (SELECT brokername FROM brokerlist WHERE brokername = ?),(SELECT broker_id FROM brokerlist WHERE brokername = ?) )")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('isssds', $user_id, $accountno,$accountname,$brokername,$revenue,$brokername);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=AddBroker failure: INSERT');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

I have added $brokername two times while binding the variable. Because I thought as we are getting broker_id from $brokername then why use seperate $broker_id varaible. Not sure where is the mistake in php coding, data is not adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is overly complicated, especially with values you are using binds for...

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO masterbroker (user_id, accountno,accountname,brokername,revenue,broker_id) 
    SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, broker_id FROM brokerlist WHERE brokername = ?")) {
```

This still uses the same binds, but reduces the query.

Comment: thank you for the short form, but data is still not adding.

Comment: Also user_id resides in another table named client. so how that works here?

Comment: I've changed the code, there was 1 less bind than their should have been.  Also the values are simply bound, same as `select 1, 'abc'` and you are binding the user_id value itself.

Comment: So does it means all will be 'ssssss' ? like this  $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $user_id, $accountno,$accountname,$brokername,$revenue,$brokername);

Comment: No - keep the same bind as you already had.  Better to keep with the proper datatypes than convert everything to strings.

Comment: Ok, I kept it as it is, but still, data is not adding.

Comment: So either add to the original question the error your getting or try finding what the data values are and try inserting the same thing through phpmyadmin to see if it works.

Comment: Now it solved sorry my mistake, I didn't included the addbroker.in.php file on addbroker.php   it's working perfectly now :) Thank you